# object of type "closure" is not subsettable in cross validation

Tags: r

I have a problem with doing cross validation
I did 10-fold cross validation and I got following error

```
Error in data[currentFold, ] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Here are codes which I used:

```
k <- 10;
folds <- cvsegments(nrow(data2), k);
result1 <- rep (NA, nrow (data2))
insituValidation <- rep (NA, nrow (data2))

for (fold in 1 : k) {
   currentFold <- folds[[fold]]

   trainDat <- data2[-currentFold,]

   model3 = nls(Height ~ a*(Diameter)^2+b*Diameter+c, data = data2, start = list(a = 1.2, b=.9,c=.5), algorithm="port")
   #end model

   # The results of the predictions of the model
   result1 [currentFold] <- predict(model3, data[currentFold,]) 
   insituValidation <- data2[currentFold,3]
}
```

I used the same codes in another dataset before and It worked But now with new dataset, the mentioned problem occurs.

Please help me to find solution.

Comment: How did you define `data`? R can't find this object and thinks you want to subset the (base R) `data` function.

Comment: the data matrix has been run under following instruction:     setwd('D:\\PhD\\Data\\Field Measurments\\Data Analysis\\')         data2 = read.table('analysis2.csv',header = TRUE, sep =',')

Comment: In your second-to-last line, replace `data[currentFold,]` with `data2[currentFold,]`. Also, in the call to `nls(...)`, why are you using `data=data2` and not `data=trainDat`??

Comment: Thank you, the problem was solved by your help:)  data2 includes both train and test data.

Comment: User "jlhoward", you were right. I should use data=trainDat instead of data=data2 in the model.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

An object of type `closure` is a function in R.

The object `data` you are using is function, so that you cannot subset it with `[` like vector. By default, the variable `data` is a function. You can find its definition [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/data.html).

You must simply have forgotten to initialize the variable `data` with a matrix.

Comment: the data matrix has been run under following instruction:     setwd('D:\\PhD\\Data\\Field Measurments\\Data Analysis\\')         dat2 = read.table('analysis2.csv',header = TRUE, sep =',')